# Pass session between controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Can you explain me a method to pass session data between controllers? in CodeIgniter?

'Cause if I have

```
$data = array('email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                                    'is_logged_in' => true);
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

On Pippo.php controller I cant' use the session in another controller, I need to check if 'is_logged_in' is set to true to create member only pages.

Comment: The given code looks perfect. can you please share with us `pippo.php` code where you use session? And are you sure about load the session class.

Comment: Once you set session you can play with it all over the project

Comment: Using `$this->session->all_userdata()` should retrieve all session data in an associative array. Rewrite it as `$this->session->set_userdata('mydata', $data)`.

Comment: Load session lib in autoload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would autoload the session library.

Then in the success part of your login controller

```
$data = array(
      'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
      'is_logged_in' => true
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Then once you have set the sessions and have been redirect to your controller

In your `parent::__construct()` area of a controller.

```
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();

  if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == false) {
    redirect('logout_controller');
  }
}
```

Comment: Have look at this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors