# How to display authenticated user data

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication

I'm working with AngularJS and PHP backend, and I'm trying to display data of authenticated user, and I have 2 views, one 'login.html' and the other 'info.html', 2 controllers (one for the login function and the other for selecting the user's data) . I implement the authentication phase but for the second step I want that when the user authenticates, it will be redirected to other view (info.html) where all the information of this user will be displayed.

I tried to use session,but it doesn't work and I don't know why. How can I store user's data from login function and use it in the second controller(second web service)?

login.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->password);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   password= "'.$password.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
       $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE EmailClient = '".$Email."'";
       mysqli_query($connect , $query);
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["token"] = $token; 
       $result['message'] ='Logged In';
       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $result['token'] = $token;

       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;
  }

       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';

$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring;
exit;
}

?>
```

info.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT Name,Adresse FROM client WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

 ?>
```

Comment: How do you store your user data? How do you authenticate? If you have a source for that data, you can [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) it.

Comment: I just checked your previous posts and your code appears to be vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I store data with $http post from controller to web service which fetch data from database, and the same thing for authentication. but the problem, in web service, to display data of authenticated user I have to put condition 'where' to mention the user, And I dont know how to do

Comment: Could you provide your current source code, as you did in the previous posts of yours? You can simply edit your question.

Comment: When I do so, I don't know why I get down votes, that's why I reformulated my question. but I will edit it now. Thank you

Comment: The downvotes might be related to the fact that you're storing passwords in plain text and that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, both of which are big no-no's.

Comment: oh! ok Thank you I will try to manage after finding solution to this problem , because I encountered this problem a long time ago and didn't find solution yet. Thank you

Comment: Does the query in info.php work?

Comment: I get this error: Undefined index: token , and I get all users who have never authenticated (where column 'token' is Null)

Comment: It would seem that the $_SESSION variable is not transferred between your 2 controllers.

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter, by any chance? Most [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094672/pass-session-between-controller) I found about passing session data between controllers are related to it.

Comment: Sincerely no, I will read about it now. Thank you